# Javascript selenium, wait until page has fully loaded

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am trying to use selenium on a webpage, however my code doesn't work consistently sometimes nothing happens, the `driver.wait` promise doesn't get fulfilled it just waits forever... My code looks like this:

```
await this.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("xpath1")));
const searchField = await this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath1"));
await searchField.click();

const input = await this.getElement("xpath2");
await input.sendKeys("SearchTerm", Key.RETURN);
```

Why does it work sometimes and sometimes not, I know the xpaths doesn't change and I have tried setting really high hardcoded `this.driver.sleep(10000)` timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

what is this :

The Implicit Wait in Selenium is used to tell the web driver to wait for a certain amount of time before it throws a "No Such Element Exception". The default setting is 0. Once we set the time, the web driver will wait for the element for that time before throwing an exception.

Selenium Web Driver has borrowed the idea of implicit waits from Watir.

In the below example we have declared an implicit wait with the time frame of 10 seconds. It means that if the element is not located on the web page within that time frame, it will throw an exception.

Basic syntax:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Edit:
If this doesn't help at allyou can try this:

```
driver.wait(function () {
return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.xpath("yourxpath"));
```

}, timeout);

//I'm actually not that fammiliar with javascript but i hope you understood what i mean

this makes the webdriver wait 10 seconds till the element you are looking for is visible

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However it did not make any difference.

Comment: @VictorGunnarsson i updated my answer check if this works

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: driver.manage(...).timeouts is not a function